# How to lose focus of YouTube player on page load?

Tags: javascript

I feel like focusing the player is in a async function or something when the page load. I am not sure but

```
Window.onload = function() {document.activeElement.blur();}
```

doesn't works.

I have to call `function() {document.activeElement.blur();}` manually afterwards, then it would work

But still, is there a way to lose focus on page load?

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener("load", e => document.activeElement.blur())` instead. `Window` (with a capital `W`) should be `window`. There is a high chance that the player is focuses asynchronously.

Comment: No that didn't work either. I think that confirms the async function